# Microsoft Teams on Windows logs are inconsistent

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing an application for Windows which detects the status of MS Teams Desktop and what happens inside the application. For this task I parse the logs.txt file located in the usual place for Teams.
Starting with the MS Teams 1.5.00.xxxx version the logs.txt includes Call IDs and this is very helpful.
But I found the same version of Teams (1.6.00.1381, the latest for today) is inconsistent.

For Win11 I can see various messages like:

```
Thu Feb 16 2023 11:10:34 GMT+0200 <23984> -- info -- DeviceCallControlManager Desktop:  + CallManager: reportIncomingCall call 6659612f-151d-433a-b362-bc86960fa39c handle value incomingConversationMRI hasVideo 0 canAnswerWithVideo 1 autoAnswer 0 appInitiatedCall 1 (causeId callControlService - onCallNotified) 
Thu Feb 16 2023 11:10:37 GMT+0200 <23984> -- info -- DeviceCallControlManager Desktop:  + CallManager: reportCallAccepted callId: 6659612f-151d-433a-b362-bc86960fa39c (causeId CallControlService - incoming call accepted) 

Thu Feb 16 2023 12:42:04 GMT+0200 <9268> -- info -- DeviceCallControlManager Desktop:  + CallManager: requestStartCall callId e73f386f-97eb-4748-abe7-1ab72629587c handle value conversationMri (causeId call Control Service - requestStartCall) 
Thu Feb 16 2023 12:42:06 GMT+0200 <9268> -- info -- DeviceCallControlManager Desktop:  + CallManager: reportOutgoingCallConnected callId e73f386f-97eb-4748-abe7-1ab72629587c. (causeId call Control Service - onCallConnected) 
Thu Feb 16 2023 12:42:33 GMT+0200 <9268> -- info -- DeviceCallControlManager Desktop:  + CallManager: reportCallEnded callId: e73f386f-97eb-4748-abe7-1ab72629587c (causeId call Control Service - currentCallEnded)
```

Those messages include Call ID.

But with Windows 10 I see no such messages in the logs.txt.

Do we have a way to enable MS Teams to include those messages in the logs.txt for Windows 10 too?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please verify if media logs setting has enabled on your Teams.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxWIK.png

Comment: Both Teams setups on Win10 and Win11 had disabled Media logs.
I enabled and re-run my tests. 
All the same: 
* For Win11 the logs.txt includes all the DeviceCallControlManager events but
* Win10 installation lacks the same events.